# Help identifying shower valve type/brand

Tags: shower, valve

I purchased a home with an outside shower that was winterized and this is all I have to help identify the brand for replacement parts.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Are you missing all the parts that are not shown here?  Or just a washer or something like that?  If this is *all* you have, why not just replace it entirely?

Comment: Disconnect it and see what the back says, if anything. But I agree with @jay613 that you're probably better off just replacing it, if the "winterized" removed parts went in the trash or with the prior house owners when they moved out. If you desperately want to save it (probably at more cost than a whole new one) having it disconnected, you can take it to a plumbing supplier. If not, you'll be halfway to installing a new one. Take this one to a scrapyard, bronze is worth some money.

Comment: Thank you!  I assume this one is pretty old even though it was installed with pex?

Comment: Looks like a Delta to me

Comment: I have no idea of the age (clearly there used to be other pipes feeding a shower at this location, based on the paint scars) I just know that it's **usually the case** that building almost anything from replacement parts (which are a profit center) soon costs more than a whole assembled thing, to the point that I doubt you can rebuild it for less than you can buy a whole new one given you are missing a lot of parts.

Comment: Assuming this shower was the kind purchased as a complete system from a big box store you can buy a whole new one, with valve, controls, and a head, for $80 to $200.  You won't find "parts" for this one for less than that, if at all.  Unless you're going for a more upscale thing where you buy components from a bathroom boutique ... but then you wouldn't want to reuse this old rough-in anyway.

Comment: Also, brass tends o get brittle with age and exposure to water, so it might break while attempting to repair it, or shortly thereafter.  That's just another reason to go with a new replacement.